# How to export pandas csv format only with character double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, quotes

I have a `dataframe` consists of numeric and character columns.

I want to export this as `csv` format and to apply double quotes only to character columns.

Is there any tips to export csv format with only character double quotes?

Below is my simple example.

Thanks.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'char' : ['100', '200'], 'num' : [700, 800]})
test.to_csv('test_out.csv', sep=",", quotechar='"',index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

>> actual result
"char","num"
"100","700"
"200","800"

>> result that I want...
"char","num"
"100",700
"200",800
```

Comment: Why do you specify `QUOTE_ALL` if that's not what you want? Just remove it and you should find that the default is at least close to what you seem to be asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` for `quoting` parameter:

```
test.to_csv('test_out.csv',  sep=",", quotechar='"',index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Test:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'char' : ['100', '200'], 'num' : [700, 800]})
print(test.to_csv( sep=",", quotechar='"',index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC))
"char","num"
"100",700
"200",800
```